# save output into string and into file bash script

Tags: bash

made a program that uses a file as input and sort the characters inside the file.

```
file4="temp.txt"
name4=$(cat $file4)
echo $name4 |  sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' > file4.txt

echo "enter how many rows :"
read cols

IFS=$'\n' a=($(cat file4.txt))
for j in $(seq ${#a[*]}); do
[[ ${a[$j-1]} = $name ]] && echo "${a[$i]}"
done

for (( i=0; i<=$(( ${#a[@]} / cols )); ++i )); do
for (( j=0; j<cols; ++j )); do
    if (( i%2 )); then idx=$(( (i + 1) / 2 * 2 * cols - j - 1 ))
    else idx=$(( (i / 2) * 2 * cols + j )); fi
    printf "%-4s  " "${a[idx]}"
done
printf "\n"
done
```

i got this output.

Output:

```
1   2   3   4   5   
10  9   8   7   6   
11  12  13  14  15  
        18  17  16
```

and i wanted to save it in a single line string and into a file.
the problem now is it should be sorted like this

```
1 10 11 12 9 2 3 8 13 18 17 14 7 4 5 6 15 16
```

i googled and what im getting is it save in right to left order

```
1 2 3 4 5 10 9 8 .....
```

any idea how?

Comment: It is not very clear what you mean. Could you elaborate a bit more and indicate what you've done so far?

Comment: @fedorqui edited my post. hopefully will be more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my answer again and again:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a data

OIFS=$IFS
while read line; do
  let n=0
  IFS=,
  for item in $line; do
    data[$n]+="|$item"
    (( ++n ))
  done
  IFS=$OIFS
done < <(sed -r -e 's@[\t ]@,@g' "$file") 

display() {
  local val=$1
  if [ ! -z "$val" ]; then
    echo -n "$val "
  fi
}

for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#data[@]} ; ++i )); do
  IFS='|'
  declare -a array=( ${data[$i]} )
  IFS=$OIFS
  if (( i % 2 )); then
    for (( j = ${#array[@]} ; j >= 0 ; --j )); do
      display "${array[$j]}"
    done
  else
    for (( j = 0 ; j < ${#array[@]} ; ++j )); do
      display "${array[$j]}"
    done    
  fi
  echo -n ','
done

echo ';'
```

The `sed` command is mandatory because the default IFS would split any space, tab or newline. You can try with `IFS=' '`.

For the input you give in your question, this will print:

```
$ file=file ./test.bash 
1 10 11 ,,9 12 ,2 ,13 ,8 ,3 14 ,,7 15 18 ,4 ,17 ,6 ,5 16 ,,,;
```

It is not the expected output, but I think you should add column separator in your output, to differentiate from empty column than space.

Comment: as a side note, you store all the output in data[0] (your for loop at the end of your script displays : `0:  1 2 3 4 5 10 9 8 7 6 11 12 13 14 15 18 17 16`).

Comment: let say if the data inside a file, how should i declare it so that it will read each char as individual array and not a line as an array

Comment: I did not test it. I'll patch it :p

Comment: thanks a lot. i tried and it worked. yea. it gives out comma in the blank space. anyway what do u mean by adding column seperator?

Comment: Instead of printing space, print a separator you are sure to not have in your output (like ":", etc). Eg: initial output should look like: `1:2:3:4\n5:6:7:8`.

Comment: hi. i managed to get it right. i didnt put any char or space when printing out output. and it worked like charm. THANKS A LOT!!!